# fullcalendar click on date number to open list of items not on date cell

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, schedule

I am using full calendar in angular 2 application. The fullcalendar opens up a list on clicking on date cell or on the date number. I am looking - If user clicks on the date link in the date cell, it should open up the list of items for that date (drill down).
If user clicks anywhere in the white space in the date cell, there should **not be** any click event and action. currently Im using onDayClick event handler, is there any other event handler to handle only date click if not is there any way to achieve this.

html -

```
     <p-schedule [events]="events" 
          [eventLimit] ="3"    (onViewRender)="loadEvents($event)"
          [eventRender]="eventRender" 
         (onEventClick)="handleEventClick($event)" 
          (navLinkDayClick)="handleDayClick($event)">
        </p-schedule>
```

component.ts

```
    import { OnInit, Component, ViewChild, Renderer, ElementRef, Input } from '@angular/core';
import * as moment from 'moment';
import { UserService } from '../../app.component.service'
declare let $: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-calendar',
  providers: [UserService],
  templateUrl: './calendar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./calendar.component.css']
})
export class CalendarComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() calendarData: any;
  @Input() calendarInfo: any;
  eventsData: any;

  newEvents: any;
  events: any;
  calendarEvents: any;
  header: any;
  calendarTitle: string;
  eventField: any;
  eventsInfo: any;
  newEventsInfo: any;
  calendarTitleJql: string;
  constructor(private userService: UserService) {  }



  ngOnInit() {
    this.calendarTitle = this.calendarInfo.Name;
    this.calendarTitleJql = this.calendarInfo.jql;
    if (this.calendarData[0]) {
      this.eventField = Object.keys(this.calendarData[0])[6];
    }

    this.eventsInfo = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.calendarData).split(this.eventField).join('eventDate'));

    this.events = this.eventsInfo.map(function (_ref) {
      var Status = _ref.Status,
        eventDate = _ref.eventDate,
        Created = _ref.Created,
        Key = _ref.Key;
      return { title: Status, start: eventDate, id: Key, tooltip: Status }; 
    });  



  }


  handleEventClick(e) {
    this.userService.showTicket(e.calEvent.id);
  }
  calendarTitleClick() {
    this.userService.search(this.calendarTitleJql);
  }



  loadEvents(e) {



    if (this) {
      let month = e.view.start._d.getMonth() + 2; 
      let year = e.view.start._d.getFullYear();  

      if (month == '13') {
        month = 1;
        year = year + 1;

      }

      this.userService.getGadgetsData(this.calendarInfo.id, "Calendar", month, year).subscribe(gadgetsData => {
        if (gadgetsData.Data.Issues[0]) {
          this.eventField = gadgetsData.Data.Issues[0].Values[5].Key;

        } 
        this.newEvents = gadgetsData.Data.Issues.map(function (o) {
          return o.Values.reduce(function (acc, _ref) {
            var Key = _ref.Key,
              Value = _ref.Value;
            return acc[Key] = Value, acc;
          }, {});
        });

        this.newEventsInfo = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.newEvents).split(this.eventField).join('eventDate'));
        this.calendarEvents = this.newEventsInfo.map(({ Key, Summary, eventDate, Created }) =>
          ({ title: Key + ' : ' + Summary, start: eventDate, id: Key, tooltip: Summary }));

        this.eventsData = this.calendarEvents.map(function (o) {

          o.start = moment.utc(o.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
          return o;

        });

         this.events = this.eventsData;


      });
    }

  }

  handleDayClick(e) {

    let dayJql;
    let dateStart = moment.utc(e.date._d).local().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    var dateClicked = moment(dateStart).add(1, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    var nextDay = moment(dateClicked).add(1, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    dayJql = this.calendarTitleJql + ' AND created >=' + dateClicked + ' AND created<= ' + nextDay;
    this.userService.search(dayJql); 

  }
```

}

Comment: If you just want an action to happen when the date link is clicked (and not the whole day) then you need to do things with the various "navLink" options detailed in the documentation here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/

Comment: @ADyson i have to use it in ng primes p-schedule. any ideas how to use it.

Comment: same way you're using the dayClick event, I should think. I only know fullCalendar itself, not that wrapper around it, but I should think the pattern of syntax in the code you've got above should be re-used, just with the different options and callbacks

Comment: @ADyson -  i tried with just changing the options to onnavLinkDayClick but in does not work even with just navLinkDayClick it doesn't.

Comment: "doesn't work" isn't an error message or problem statement. From your comment I've got only a basic idea of roughly what you did, and there could be any number of possible problems, including basic syntax errors, which might cause it to "not work". I can't help based on such a vague statement. Please edit the question to show what you tried, and report any errors or unexpected behaviour you experience (hint: check your console for any syntax or runtime errors. If you don't get any, try setting breakpoints in the code to see if the callbacks actually run.)

Comment: @ADyson did set up the debugger and found that on clcik of the number of day it is not triggering the function. i think it is not able to capture navLinkDayClick from p-schedule.

Comment: ok well we need to see the code then

Comment: @ADyson updated the question with full code

Comment: No I meant the changed version where you tried to apply the navLinks. Don't need the rest of your code really I don't think.

Comment: @ADyson i have updated html code.

Comment: As per the documentation you need to set the option "navLinks: true" before the callback will work. Read it more carefully.

Comment: @ADyson - ok but where to write that in html inside p-schedule or in .ts file?

Comment: Well it's an option just like `[eventLimit] ="3"` so I would suggest it should be done in the same style.